# How to connect to VPN from Linux and send only part of traffic via it

Tags: linux, vpn, routing

I have target host, username and password. I can connect in Windows via Cisco AnyConnect. But all traffic goes via that tunnel. Under Linux I used to use Vpnc, but it requires also additional secure parameters. But with vpnc and Linux I can do with traffic almost everything. So, how to connect to VPN from Linux only with target host, user and password?

Comment: Your title does not reflect your question

Comment: Could you, please, help to edit it, so it will be sounds correctly?